# Pip will not install the WebPageTest API

Tags: python-3.x, pip, webpagetest

I am trying to get started using WebPageTest API for batch analysis of URLs.  Unfortunately I've fallen down at the first hurdle - the api does not seem to want to install.

I have updated pip, I have created a fresh virtual env in case something else I have installed is interfering.  Unfortunately I can't get rid of the following error:

```
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1
```

I have tried a manual installation at the directory specified by the error, but this does not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing after updating your setuptools using this command:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

you can refer to [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/3884) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I have already Googled the issue - that thread was the first thing I found and have already tried the suggested fixes.  
Do you have anything else I could try

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

pip install git+https://github.com/khilnani/webpagetest.py@master

It is registered under the issue tab on GitHub.